# Datatype in VBA. Getting overflow error with constants but works fine with variables

Tags: vba

May be its very basic and sound like a pretty stupid question. But I am confused with this. So, when I try to do 1000 * 1000 in a double variable  I get an overflow error. Where as for I keep on multiplying  the  variable it self, it works fine. Can some one please explain, why?

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Double

x = 1000 * 1000 ' ~~>> Give OverFlow Error. WHY ?

x=1000
x = x * x * x * x ' ~~>> Works Fine

MsgBox x

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA does a lot things implicitly without asking the user. That makes the language very easy to learn and use. At the same time, it can render things a bit complicated as in this case. The number 1000 is not declared and therefore VBA is automatically treating it as an integer: `Debug.Print VarType(1000)`. To "declare" a number as `double` simply add `#` to the end: `x = 1000# * 1000` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264155%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah. VBA how I love thee.

In this case, it is treating the 1000 as an integer, which in VB6 is 16-bit(max value of 32767), so it is overflowing because 1 million is too large to fit in an integer.

You can "cast" the literal to a specific type by using terrible type characters.

Full list here. Yes, the feature is preserved in .NET.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx

```
Sub test()

    Dim x As Double

    x = 1000& * 1000&     ' Long literals

    x = 1000
    x = x * x * x * x ' ~~>> Works Fine

    MsgBox x

End Sub
```